# Adding an array of values to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox, submit

I've got a foreach where I create an array out of id's, based on the submitted selected checkboxes from my form (which are `checkbox[$id]. So I end up with:

[image: Checkboxes]

Where 1, 2 and 3 are the submitted id's from the form. So far so good.

Now I also have an input field `amount[$id]`in my form. When selecting a checkbox, I can enter an amount for that row and submit the results. I need to add the values of `amount` to my array if id's. My end result should look like this:

```
[1 => ['amount' => '10'], 2 => ['amount' => '12'], 3 => ['amount' => '5'] // And so on
```

I tried merging, and array_push, but I seem to be doing it wrong, since I cannot figure it out. Any pointers?

Comment: Maybe using `array_combine`?

Comment: Never used it, and that should be it I guess! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Comment: `array_combine` will help if keys of array will be just numbers, but not arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$result = [];
$ids = [1,2,3];   // I suppose it is `$_POST['ids']`
$amounts = [1 => 10, 2 => 11, 3 => 22];   // I suppose it is `$_POST['amount']`
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if (!empty($amounts[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = ['amount' => $amounts[$id]];
    }
}
```

Using `array_combine` as advised in comments can be used only if sizes of arrays are equal. So if you have something like:

```
$ids = [1,2,4];
$amounts = [1 => 10, 2 => 11, 3 => 0, 4 => 22];
print_r(array_combine($ids, $amounts));   // PHP Warning
```

And second fact - `array_combine` won't create values as arrays. So

```
$ids = [1,2,3];
$amounts = [1 => 10, 2 => 11, 3 => 10];
print_r(array_combine($ids, $amounts));   // no subarrays here
```

Comment: Thanks, was trying to get it to work with the `array_combine`, but I will use this method instead and see if it works, seems like a better solution.

Comment: Worked like a charm with some tweaks, using it with laravel. Nice solution!